# Rank and choose the 5 models that showed the best result for each group

Tags: r, list, model, regression, tibble

This is an example data.

```
ind1 <- rnorm(99)
ind2 <- rnorm(99)
ind3 <- rnorm(99)
ind4 <- rnorm(99)
ind5 <- rnorm(99)
dep <- rnorm(99, mean=ind1)
group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=33)
df <- data.frame(dep,group, ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4, ind5)
```

Here simple linear regression model has been fitted on every combination of variables in df after grouped by categorical variable. The result is satisfied. But my original data has much more than 5 variables. It is hard to see and compare the results in this list. So I would like to choose the best 5 models for each group from the resulting list (tibble_list) based on AIC value. It will be highly appreciated if someone could help me to do so.

```
indvar_list <- lapply(1:5, function(x) 
  combn(paste0("ind", 1:5), x, , simplify = FALSE))

formulas_list <- rapply(indvar_list, function(x)
  as.formula(paste("dep ~", paste(x, collapse="+"))))

run_model <- function(f) {    
  df %>% 
    nest(-group) %>% 
    mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(f, data = .)),
           results1 = map(fit, glance),
           results2 = map(fit, tidy)) %>% 
    unnest(results1) %>% 
    unnest(results2) %>% 
    select(group, term, estimate, r.squared, p.value, AIC) %>% 
    mutate(estimate = exp(estimate))
}

tibble_list <- lapply(formulas_list, run_model)
tibble_list
```

Comment: Can you define *"best model"*? It could be any combination/weighting of p-value, R<sup>2</sup>, R<sup>2</sup>-adj, AIC, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would  be to bind the rows into a single dataset with a `.id` column, then `arrange` by 'group', 'AIC', grouped by 'group', `filter` the rows having the first five `unique` 'index'

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(tibble_list, .id = 'index') %>% 
    arrange(group, AIC) %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    filter(index %in% head(unique(index), 5)) 
# A tibble: 51 x 7
# Groups:   group [3]
#   index group term        estimate r.squared  p.value   AIC
#   <chr> <fct> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1     A     (Intercept)    0.897     0.319 0.000620  79.5
# 2 1     A     ind1           2.07      0.319 0.000620  79.5
# 3 7     A     (Intercept)    0.883     0.358 0.00129   79.5
# 4 7     A     ind1           2.14      0.358 0.00129   79.5
# 5 7     A     ind3           0.849     0.358 0.00129   79.5
# 6 8     A     (Intercept)    0.890     0.351 0.00153   79.9
# 7 8     A     ind1           2.12      0.351 0.00153   79.9
# 8 8     A     ind4           0.860     0.351 0.00153   79.9
# 9 19    A     (Intercept)    0.877     0.387 0.00237   80.0
#10 19    A     ind1           2.18      0.387 0.00237   80.0
## … with 41 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I just run this code but it gives the error "Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) :  incorrect size (99) at position 1, expecting : 4320"

Comment: @SunRise  Is that based on the example you showed.  I am not getting any error.  I used `set.seed(24)` to generate the example

Comment: @SunRise What is the `dplyr/purrr` versions you have

Comment: Versions are: packageVersion("dplyr"): [1] ‘0.7.8’
packageVersion("purrr"): [1] ‘0.3.2’

Comment: @SunRise are you using the same example data

Comment: @SunRise I have `packageVersion('dplyr')
#[1] ‘0.8.0.1’`

Comment: I am using it on my original data which might cause the error.

Comment: @SunRise  May be your original data structure is different compared to the one you showed.  Do you get error with `bind_rows(tibble_list, .id = 'index')`

Comment: Ookey. it solved. I re-started calculation after deleting R memory. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SunRise  It is possible that you save the objects into R memory when you are close the session.  I would never keep any objects in the memory as it can pollute the env

Comment: @ Akrun. yup I agree not to keep after I discovered it. By the way, Is it possible to select the models based on both P<0.05 and AIC for each group? if so, how should I change this code?

Comment: @SunRise Yes, you can do a `filter(p.value < 0.05)` before the `arrange` step